# matching only numbers in a regex string for redirect

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am using a redirection plugin for wordpress ad have no experience with regex.

I have a url that can have anything after the url, but I only want to redirect if only numbers appear and nothing else, such that of the following urls only the last one would get a match:

```
http://j.net/contact
http://j.net/c4t
http://j.net/4con
http://j.net/4co5
http://j.net/anything/123  * this should fail
http://j.net/456           * this should pass
```

I came up with this:

```
(\d+)$
```

to:

```
article/$1
```

But I ended up in an infinite loop.

Edit: the loop seems to come into play when navigating to:

```
http://j.net/1289
```

Or:

```
http://j.net/dribble/1289
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems to work fine, after escaping the `/` character 
See the example: http://regex101.com/r/cX4bV6/2

PS. i'm not sure what language you are using and whether wordpress would support it.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I'll go back to the Drawing board and give it another go. It's a plugin, and I'm not sure what's happening behind the scenes. It turns out I'm not passing in the whole URLs as I indicated above, just everything from the '('. I've amended my plugins data, and some URLs work, but most are still getting caught up in an endless loop. This is closer.  http://regex101.com/r/cX4bV6/3 I'll keep plugging away. Thanks.

Comment: A comedy of errors, not limited to my not escaping, but also browser cache so that even when I did get things right, the browser still had it wrong. Thanks for the post since I thought it was just me